# convert string to xml and update value field using boost

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I have a string like this

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Parameters>
>     <Parameter id="ID_1" value="1"/>
>     <Parameter id="ID_2" value="000293604959"/>
>     <Parameter id="ID_3" value="MIIDzzCCAregAwIBAgIQBU7WUKqJI"/>          //Variable length data
>     <Parameter id="ID_4" value="MIIDyDCCArCgAwIBAgIGAWSjA2NaMA0GCSqGS"/>  //Variable length data
>     <Parameter id="ID_5" value="MIIDcDCCAligAwIBAgIEATMzfzANBgkqhk"/>     //Variable length data
>     <Parameter id="ID-6" value="WIN_10_64_bit"/> </Parameters>
```

And I want this to be printed as (expected output) means hide ID_3, ID_4 and ID_5 data.

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Parameters>
>     <Parameter id="ID_1" value="1"/>
>     <Parameter id="ID_2" value="000293604959"/>
>     <Parameter id="ID_3" value="Sensitive Data"/>         //Variable length data
>     <Parameter id="ID_4" value="Sensitive Data"/>         //Variable length data
>     <Parameter id="ID_5" value="Sensitive Data"/>         //Variable length data
>     <Parameter id="ID-6" value="WIN_10_64_bit"/>
```

Till now I have tried this but got no luck. Kindly let me know where i am doing wrong to update value field as real value to Sensitive Data.

```
void hideData(string request)
{
stringstream ss;
ss.str(request);
boost::property_tree::ptree pt1;
boost::property_tree::read_xml(ss, pt1);
ostringstream oss;
string finalStringToPrint;

if (!pt1.empty())
{
    BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type const& node, pt1.get_child("Parameters"))
    {
        if (node.first == "Parameter")
        {
            string id = node.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.id").data();
            if (id == "ID_3")
            {
                string value = node.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.value").data();
                value.erase();
                value.assign("Sensitive Data");
                pt1.put_value(value);
            }
            if (id == "ID_4")
            {
                string value = node.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.value").data();
                value.erase();
                value.assign("Sensitive Data");
                pt1.put_value(value);
            }
            if (id == "ID_5")
            {
                string value = node.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.value").data();
                value.erase();
                value.assign("Sensitive Data");
                pt1.put_value(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
boost::property_tree::write_xml(oss, pt1, boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<string>(' ', 4));
finalStringToPrint = oss.str();
cout << finalStringToPrint << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to modify data in a certain node, so call `get_child`, holds reference to returned child node and then call `put_value` on this node:

```
            if (id == "ID_3")
            {
                auto& child = node.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.value");
                child.put_value("Sensitive Data");
            }
            if (id == "ID_4")
            {
                auto& child = node.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.value");
                child.put_value("Sensitive Data");
            }
            if (id == "ID_5")
            {
                auto& child = node.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.value");
                child.put_value("Sensitive Data");
            }
```

and while iterating you need to iterate over elements without `const` in foreach, because you modify items:

```
BOOST_FOREACH( boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type & node, pt1.get_child("Parameters"))
```

**EDIT**

To remove whitespaces you can use `property_tree::xml_parser::trim_whitespace` as 
input `read_xml`:

```
boost::property_tree::read_xml(ss, pt1, boost::property_tree::xml_parser::trim_whitespace);
```

Comment: every iteration of BOOST_FOREACH loop adding a new empty line in between <Parameters> and <Parameter> tag. How to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks. Accepted.